# Multiple ConfigurationManager Changes Failing To Update DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext, configurationmanager

**Short version:**

I need to loop through three different connection strings in a single winforms app (DEV, LIVE and DEMO). I use ConfigurationManager to update the base connection string. This works. However, my DBContext only respects the first change to the connection string. The rest are ignored.

**Details:**

These databases were all built, code first, using the same context.

I have a single connection string in my App.config named MY_DB.

**Here is the Main loop:**

```cs
// Get the necessary Config values
string DEFAULT_DB = "MY_DB";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConnectionStringsSection csSection = config.ConnectionStrings;
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = csSection.ConnectionStrings[DEFAULT_DB].ConnectionString;
string provider = csSection.ConnectionStrings[DEFAULT_DB].ProviderName;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Initial: {0}", builder["Initial Catalog"]));


// Loop through my databases
string[] catalogArray = { "live", "demo", "dev" };

foreach (string catalog in catalogArray)
{
    builder["Initial Catalog"] = catalog;
    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Remove(DEFAULT_DB);
    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(DEFAULT_DB, builder.ConnectionString, provider));
    config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

    // Tried both of these. Same results.
    // ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Processing: {0}", csSection.ConnectionStrings[DEFAULT_DB].ConnectionString));

    DoDBStuff();

    // Also tried this. No joy.
    // System.GC.Collect();
}
```

**Here is DoDBStuff:**

```cs
public void DoDBStuff()
    {
        using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
        {
            string connstr = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connstr);
            string context = builder.InitialCatalog;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("DoDBStuff is Using: {0}", context));
        }
    }
```

**Here is the output (sanitized):**

```cs
/*
Initial: dev
Processing: Data Source=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=live;User ID=nope;Password=supersecure;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
DoDBStuff is Using: live
Processing: Data Source=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=demo;User ID=nope;Password=supersecure;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
DoDBStuff is Using: live
Processing: Data Source=1.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=dev;User ID=nope;Password=supersecure;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
DoDBStuff is Using: live
*/
```

So, dear Overflowers, why does the app insist on only using the first configuration 'override' and ignore the others?

By the way, I am well aware that I can do something like this:

```cs
MyContext db = new MyContext("CONNECTION_STRING_NAME");
```

I don't want to do that. Mostly because of a lot of static methods I call that have their own internal using. Like this...

```cs
public static Customer ById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
            {
                return db.Customer.Find(id);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

There are just too many of those to override them all.

Help!